# Display images in list-inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list, gallery

I want to display images inline, but instead of this they appear vertically and the horizontal scrollbar isn't come up. How can i make the screen scrollable without define exact width and how can i format the images to smaller than the screen vertically without explicit height? No js tricks. Thx

```
<section class="project-section">
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
        <article class="project-data">
            <h1>@Model.CurrentTitleText()</h1>
            <p>@Model.CurrentDescriptionText()</p>
        </article>
    </li>
    @foreach (var elem in Model.ProjectInclude)
    {
        <li>
            <article class="project-item-container fit-container">
                <img class="fit-container" src="@Url.Action("Render", "Image", new { file = elem.Media.FileName })/" />
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(elem.Media.CurrentTitleText()))
                {
                    <h6>@elem.Media.CurrentTitleText()</h6>
                }
                @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(elem.Media.CurrentDescriptionText()))
                {
                    <p>@elem.Media.CurrentDescriptionText()</p>
                }
            </article>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.project-section {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.fit-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.project-itemlist {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.project-item-container {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your list display inline:

CSS:

```
 .list-inline li{

   display:inline-block;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/scottstreit/pen/wKJXKV) and mocked up your html. When I do so it displays correctly. I would suggest you check to ensure bootstrap is being loaded. The `list-inline` class is already set to `display: inline-block` if your properly loading bootstrap.

```
<section class="project-section">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li>
      <article class="project-data">
        <h1>Inline Images</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </article>
    </li>
    <li>
      <article class="project-item-container fit-container">
        <img class="fit-container" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" />
        <h6>Sample text</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
      </article>
    </li>

    <li>
      <article class="project-item-container fit-container">
        <img class="fit-container" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" />
        <h6>Sample text</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
      </article>
    </li>

    <li>
      <article class="project-item-container fit-container">
        <img class="fit-container" src="http://www.placehold.it/200x200" />
        <h6>Sample text</h6>
        <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>

.project-section {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.fit-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.project-itemlist {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.project-item-container {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It is working until the whole content is not as wide as the screen, if it's wide enough the list elements split to rows and not expand the width of the screen. You can check this if you have try with for example 2000px wide images. I'd like the achive an effect like on this site:
[link](http://www.diegolevy.com/index.php?/project/sangre/)

Comment: If you remove the `fit-container` class from the `<article>` element it should scroll horizontally as you would like it to.